# Managing user groups in php session

Tags: php, arrays, session

I need to devide connected users into groups of 3 users each. I do not know how many will connect. Let's say there will be 10 users for test purpose. That means, there has to be 4 groups in session.
Problem:  I cannot identify users. The only trigger is a button in form, which has a post method.

I have started something to create, but can't figure it out, whether it is a right logic for this goal

**index.php**

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if (isset($_POST['join']) === true) {
    if (empty($_SESSION)) {
       $room = generateRandomString(25); // hash
       $_SESSION[$room]['users'] = 1;
    } else {
       $last_room = end($_SESSION);
       if ($last_room['users'] < 3) {
          end($_SESSION)['users'] = $last_room['users'] + 1;
       } else {
          $new_room='';
          $_SESSION[$new_room] = array(generateRandomString(25));
          $_SESSION[$new_room]['users'] = 1;
       }
   }
   var_dump($_SESSION); // screenshot is below
 }
?>
```

[image]

Every user which clicks the button on the same page gets only different hash and users = 1 with the code above.

What I was trying to make is:

```
Array
(
     [7YzEbT4q7FjrB2Y5SDNVZMHQk] => Array
         (
             [users] => 3
         )
     [f84gh304tu34g93ug9ug39g3g] => Array
         (
             [users] => 3
         )

     [ndmh5gh304tu34g93ug9ug3g4] => Array
         (
             [users] => 3
         )

     [56404tu34g93ug9ug3974tnm8] => Array
         (
             [users] => 1 // or 2 or 3, depends upon amount of connected users 
         )
 )
```

Where is an error?

Comment: The “error” probably lies in you completely misunderstanding how sessions work, I suppose? Each user has their _own_ session, that’s more or less _the point_ of sessions.

Comment: Understood. In fairness I must say, I was thinking about some server-side session.

Comment: PHP itself does not provide a mechanism to store data for access by multiple script instances. The session mechanism can be “abused” to achieve that – if you specify the session ID yourself, and just make it the _same_ one, for all clients. But that comes with its own potential side effects, and would need extra work, if you need a “real” user-specific session in parallel, so I would rather advice against that. Strong the data into a file or database would be the rather trivial alternatives; you can also look into stuff like “shared memory”, if you need something high-performance.

Comment: Will this class be helpful? https://github.com/ninsuo/php-shared-memory - just your professional opinion for shared memory.

Comment: Yeah, I guess something like that should do. PHP has its own implementation, https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php, but that is quite cumbersome to use. I can’t tell right now whether this library needs the PHP extension to be available in the background, or has its completely own implementation.